# Properties of this object

Tags: javascript, sql, dotnetnuke-module

```
function getCarrierNames(carrIDValue) {
    var carrName = ge_returnsGrid_carrier_name();
    carrIDValue = carrIDValue.toUpperCase();
    //carrName.value = carrArray[carrIDValue];

    var CName = { [sqlQuery:
        select name 
        from plant.carrier 
        where ltrim(cast([carrier_id] as varchar)) like carrIDValue
    ] };

    carrName.value = CName;
}
```

In the carrName field i am getting [object object]

Is there a way to list all the properties in a object so i can figure out where the results are stored?

Comment: Use `console.log(carrName)` to see the value.

Comment: That's exactly what you're doing.

Comment: What framework are you using that allows you to build a query directly in JavaScript like that?

Comment: indoo, inside dotnetnuke. Cleaning up some horrid old code from another developer.

Comment: Are you actually asking about `CName`, not `carrName`?

Comment: Ok, you might want to add another relevant tag to show that this is related to DotNetNuke. As it is, that is not valid JS syntax.

Comment: My guess is that `CName` is an array, where each element is a row of results. So you probably want `CName[0].name`.

Comment: I cant create a new tag without 2k rep

Comment: Also, are these queries synchronous? If not, don't you need to get the results in a callback?

Comment: (looks like someone else added it) There should be a few DotNetNuke tags you can choose from

Comment: I am getting object{}